# Magnetic Lock Power Source

Tags: power-supply, electromagnetism, magnetics, electromagnetic, magnet

I have just installed a 12v 350mA 600lb Electrical Magnetic Interior Door Lock.  I have tested it with a cheap 12V, 1A DC Switching Power Supply Adapter and it works just like it was designed.  I have several extra 12v 3A Constant Current Source LED Drivers that I am not using and I was wondering if there is any advantage to using an LED 12 3A CCS to power the Magnetic Lock vs using the 12v 1A Adapter.  I do have a basic understanding of the difference between a Constant Current Source and Constant Voltage Source but in this specific application, I wanted to know if one is more reliable over the other or if one will provide a better magnetic contact force for the lock.

Comment: Why not just use the vendor's recommended power supply?

Comment: So, you want to try to force about 8 times the nominal current through the electromagnet?

Comment: A constant current source will try to jack up the voltage to make the rated current flow.  It WANTS to deliver 3A.  If it manages that (if it can raise the voltage high enough) then it will force 3A through your electromagnetic lock - burning out the coil and possibly destroying electronic parts along the way.

Comment: the only potential advantage would be unplanned excitement on a dull day...

Answer (score 3):

At DC, the ratio of voltage to current is fixed by the resistance of the wire the magnet is wound with.  If the magnet is specified as "12 V, 350 mA", then you *should* be able to run it with a 12 V constant voltage source or a 350 mA constant current source.

However, most likely the vendor expects you to use a constant voltage source.  In that case 350 mA is more of a guide as to how much current it will take than a spec.  It *should* take 350 mA at 12 V, but that could also be the guaranteed not to exceed current, with the actual current likely lower.

The safest thing to do is to measure the current with 12 V applied.  You can then safely supply that much current, regulating for current instead of voltage.

All that said, I would be surprised if there are any problems if you feed it with a fixed 350 mA, even if the resulting voltage is a bit higher than 12 V.  The issue will be heat dissipation.  If this is from a reputable manufacturer, then there should be enough margin built into the heat dissipation capabilities so that 350 mA really should be fine.

No, you should not drive it with a 3 A current source.  That would make it get very hot very fast and almost certainly cause permanent damage to it, and possibly start a fire.

Comment: Since 3/0.35 is 8.57, and the square of that is about 73, there's your power ratio. Yeah, I think "very fast" is about right.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response.  After measuring the actual V & mA I get 12.22v & 319mA.  After your clerification, I think using the 12v Constant Voltage is best.  I forgot that with the LED Drive, I still need a Current Limiting Resistor.  I could add one here but it is a waste to add more current just to limit it with a resistor.  Thanks again for your help.